# Using Jenkins for pushing code in Autoscale AWS Instance

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to push code on AWS EC2 instances (in Autoscaling mode) using Jenkins as soon as new version of code is pushed in GitHub. Jenkins has AWS EC2 plugin but it is managing autoscaling on it own and people's are facing issue even CPU is high when they test with Stress Utility. So . how i should create it?
Edit: Exploring little bit. I have a code on Github. I want to push code to EC2 instances running in Autoscaling mode using Jenkins. Means as soon as I put new code in Github it will automatically build and deploy to EC2 instances (under Autoscaling) or if new instances are created from basic AMI then as soon as it spins up Jenkins will push code to it from Github

Comment: the  AWS EC2 plugin is to spin Jenkins slaves to run your jobs, not to deploy application code. I'm not quite sure if I understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I have a code in Github. I want to push code to EC2 instances running in Autoscaling mode using Jenkins. Means based on as soon as i put new code in Github it will automatically build and deploy to EC2 instances (under Autoscaling) or if new instances are created from basic basic AMI then as soon as it spin up Jenkins will push code to it from Github.

Comment: then, i think, what you need is build a new AMI and then change the autoscaling to use the new AMI. you can use jenkins to do that, but you will need to write a script that does that.

Comment: That is a one of the workaround.  I believe this is general situation i.e. suppose any organization has common jenkins server for multi account/cloud deployment and either in AWS / Azure most of the application has Autoscaling / VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale set) as their HA method. So i just want to know how they are doing it generally? I know if there is nno jenkins server then we can use AWS Native tool like code build, code deploy etc. for this but what if we have jenkins server ?

Comment: jenkins will run whatever you configure to Jenkins run. the Jenkins ec2 plugin is not suitable for what you want to do.